# Ошибка подключению к PPTPD

Tags: centos, ppp

Подключаюсь с win10 к своему вертуальному серверу как к vpn. На сервере CONTOS 7. Поставил PPTPD.

Подключаюсь, Идёт проверка данных для входа.
Долго идёт.

Делаю

```
$ netstat -alpn | grep :1723**      

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1723            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12870/pptpd         
tcp        0      0 172.31.1.100:1723       212.111.203.178:63634   ESTABLISHED 13226/pptpd
```

---

Потом win10 говорит **не удается подключится к удаленному компьютеру поэтому порт подключения закрыт**

Тогда проверка портов говорит

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1723            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12870/pptpd         
tcp        0      0 172.31.1.100:1723       212.111.203.178:64962   TIME_WAIT   -
```

***Логи***

```
  Plugin /usr/lib64/pptpd/pptpd-logwtmp.so loaded.
pptpd-logwtmp: $Version$
using channel 18
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/1
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x37a07661> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x37a07661> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x37a07661> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x37a07661> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x37a07661> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x37a07661> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x37a07661> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x37a07661> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x37a07661> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x37a07661> <pcomp> <accomp>]
LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Connection terminated.
Modem hangup
```

**options.pptpd**

```
name pptpd
logfile /var/log/pptpd.log 
# Запрещаем откровенно не безопасные
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
# Требуем значительно более безопасные
require-mschap-v2
require-mppe-128
# DNS от Google
#ms-dns 8.8.8.8
#ms-dns 8.8.4.4
# DNS от Yandex
ms-dns 77.88.8.8
ms-dns 77.88.8.1
proxyarp
nodefaultroute
lock
nobsdcomp
novj
novjccomp
debug
#nologfd
noipx
#nopcomp
#noaccomp
```

Comment: Логи не нашёл:(

Comment: Добавил логи в тему

Comment: Добавил, обновил

Comment: как видите, с точки зрения программы *pppd* — она лишь посылает конфигурационные запросы по протоколу *lcp* (`sent ... lcp confreq ...`), но ничего не получает в ответ. возможно, пакеты где-то блокируются (сервер, клиент, промеж. сеть), возможно клиент «не понимает, что от него хотят» (а так как клиент — программа под *ms/windows*, узнать от неё что-то внятное практически невозможно). как видно из лога, используется два вида компрессии — pcomp и accomp. попробуйте поотключать их последовательно (опции `nopcomp` и `noaccomp`).

Comment: Отключил, пока-что не помогло.:(

Comment: Добавил options.pptpd к теме

Comment: один из возможных вариантов блокирования: [No GRE received by PPTP Client](http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-diagnosis.phtml#client_no_gre_rx). ну и полистайте приведённую страницу — она как раз диагностике проблем посвящена.

Comment: Сделал modprobe ip_gre, iptables -A INPUT -p gre -j ACCEPT в итоге подключился! Теперь нет подключения к интернету))

Comment: Рано радовался, снова перестало подключаться :(

Comment: После modprobe nf_nat_pptp  заработало.

Comment: оформите, пожалуйста, ответ на вопрос. ну, чтоб вопрос не «висел» неотвеченным.

Comment: Забыл сохранить service iptables save

Comment: Всё так-же не коннектит ещё:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modprobe ip_gre
modprobe nf_nat_pptp
iptables -A INPUT -p gre -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
 в итоге подключился! Теперь нет подключения к интернету))

Comment: Всё-равно иногда не коннектится:(

Comment: Перестало совсем. Не решение проблемы